# Kotlin - Loop Zero Times

Tags: kotlin

Since there is [no traditional loop](https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/for-loop) in Kotlin (as per [this article](https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/for-loop)), how would you write a for loop in Kotlin that loops *n* times, or specifically, zero times if *n* is zero?

The equivalent in Java would be

```java
int n = 0;

for (int index = 0; index < n; index++) {
    // do this n times...
}
```

Comment: `index < n` will never be `true` ..

Comment: @MartinZeitler You sure? I tested before hand, `n = 0` executes zero times, whereas `n = 1` executes one time.

Comment: The simple `FOR I = 1 TO 10`-style loop is older and arguably [_more_ traditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#Traditional_for-loops) than the C-style one…

Comment: I wonder what do you mean by "traditional" loop? This explains [how loops are working in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#for-loops)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `repeat` for this instead of a `for` loop or a range...

```
val n = 5
repeat(n) {
    // ...
}
```

If you need to use the counter, you can either refer to it with the default `it` or rename it:

```
repeat(n) { i ->
   // Do something with i
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [ranges and progressions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html)

```
val n = 5
for (a in 0 until n) {
  //Do something
}
```